# How to convert a text bitstring to a net ip address in go

Tags: string, go, data-conversion

I can convert a net.IP address to a bitstring using `Sprintf`:

```
fmt.Sprintf("%08b%08b%08b%08b",net.IP[0],net.IP[1],net.IP[2],net.IP[3])
```

How can I convert back from the string `"11000000101010000000000000000000"` to `"192.168.0.0"`?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us some of your code? What's the context?

Answer (score 0):

First convert the bitstring back into an integer and then take the parts of the IP address out by shifting appropriately.

```golang
s := "11000000101010000000000000000000"
output, _ := strconv.ParseInt(s, 2, 64)

ipb := []byte{
    byte(output >> 24),
    byte(output >> 16),
    byte(output >> 8),
    byte(output),
}

ip := fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", ipb[0], ipb[1], ipb[2], ipb[3])
fmt.Println(ip)
```

or

```golang
ip := net.IPv4(ipb[0], ipb[1], ipb[2], ipb[3])
fmt.Println(ip.String())
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thank you for the help and code example.  I changed ParseInt to ParseUint and all looks good.

Answer (score 0):

```
func binaryStringToIPv4(bs string) (uint8, uint8, uint8, uint8) {
    var ip uint32

    for i, c := range bs {
        // 31 = len(bs)-1
        ip |= uint32(byte(c)-'0') << (31 - i)
    }
    return uint8(ip >> 24), uint8(ip >> 16), uint8(ip >> 8), uint8(ip)
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.